# How can i access below code in tcl

Tags: tcl

I want to get values of ya0,ya1 using for loop.
But below code is not working.

```
set ya0 12  
set ya1 16  
for {set i 0}  {$i < 2} {incr i} {  
puts "$ya{$i}"  
}
```

Answer (score 5):

You're nearly there.

```
set ya0 12  
set ya1 16  
for {set i 0} {$i < 2} {incr i} {  
    puts [set ya$i]
}
```

This is slightly simpler but might not be applicable in your code:

```
set ya0 12  
set ya1 16  
foreach varname {ya0 ya1} {
    puts [set $varname]
}
```

In both cases, the `set` command is used to get the value from a variable whose name isn't known until runtime.

If you want to construct variable names from a root (`ya`) and a variable suffix/index (0, 1, ...), an `array` can be useful:

```
set ya(0) 12  
set ya(1) 16  
for {set i 0} {$i < 2} {incr i} {  
    puts $ya($i)
}
```

Sometimes when one does this, what one really wants is a list:

```
set ya [list 12 16]
for {set i 0} {$i < 2} {incr i} {  
    puts [lindex $ya $i]
}
# or (better)
foreach val $ya {
    puts $val
}
```

Documentation: [for](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/for.htm), [foreach](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/foreach.htm), [incr](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/incr.htm), [lindex](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/lindex.htm), [list](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/list.htm), [puts](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/puts.htm), [set](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/set.htm), [variable substitution](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/Tcl.htm#M12)

Answer (score 1):

## subst / set

You can use subst or set to evaluate the value of a variable name.

subst:

```
set ya0 12  
set ya1 16  
for {set i 0}  {$i < 2} {incr i} {
    set varname ya${i}
    puts [subst "$$varname"]
}
```

set:

```
set ya0 12  
set ya1 16  
for {set i 0}  {$i < 2} {incr i} {
    set varname ya${i}
    puts [set $varname]
}
```

output:

```
12
16
```